# Logging error Traceback (most recent call last):File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1025, in emit msg = self.format(record)

Tags: python, class, object, logging, python-logging

I am trying to make a custom logging class.

```
import logging

logging_level = 'INFO'

class Logger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.getLevelName(logging_level))
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s%(levelname)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S%p')
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler('logFile.log')
        file_handler.setFormatter(format)
        stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler() #if we want to print to consol
        stream_handler.setFormatter(format)
        self.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
        self.logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

    
    def logInfo(self):
        self.logger.info("Hi")

log = Logger()
log.logInfo()
```

I keep receiving this error

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1025, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 869, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'format'
Call stack:
  File "/home/usr/.../python_scripts/Logger.py", line 22, in <module>
    log.logInfo()
  File "/home/usr/.../python_scripts/Logger.py", line 19, in logInfo
    self.logger.info("Hi")
Message: 'Hi'
Arguments: ()
```

I must be doing something wrong the the oo programming in python. IT makes the log file but it is empty.

Comment: You probably wanted to call `self.logger.info`, not `self.info`. Please, next time, extract a [mcve], that would probably have resolved it for you already.

Comment: You can [edit] your question in order to add the backtrace (properly formatted) and then delete this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo in your `logInfo` method and in the "format" paramater which should have been `formatter`, I also changed a bit the `setLevel` method to use `getLevelName` so you could change it dynamically:

```
import logging

logging_level = 'INFO'

class Logger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.getLevelName(logging_level))
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s%(levelname)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S%p')
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler('logFile.log')
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler() #if we want to print to consol
        stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
        self.logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

    
    def logInfo(self):
        self.logger.info("Hi")

log = Logger()
log.logInfo()
```

Output

```
07/18/2022 06:24:39PM - __main__INFO: Hi
```

Comment: Would you know any reason to why I am getting that traceback?

Comment: Solved it, my file name was the issue